# How long does it take to restore a Facebook app if it was deleted by admin?

Tags: facebook

I, as an admin of a Facebook app our company is developing, have accidentally deleted this app from Facebook. Facebook now allows to restore a recently deleted app from Developer Tools&Support page in such situations, but it needs to send an email to a contact mailbox. It's been 3 hours since we sent a restore request, and so far nothing came in - I have checked my mail server, spam filter, etc. Does anybody know how long does it usually take to restore a deleted app - are these mails sent automatically, or such requests are moderated manually?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. You’ll have to wait as long as it takes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this can be closed. Apparently the notification should come instantly, as was the case with my other app, so the problem lies either in Facebook not sending the notification or my mail server not receiving it.

Comment: Hi Andrey, i know this is an old topic but did you get the email eventually? The same thing happened to me today.

Comment: Hi Prem; I reported this to FB as a bug related to their App Dashboard: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/266719523703576/ and they manually sent me an email to restore the app. Basically, you shouldn't use email accounts like 'info@' 'support@' etc. for your app; I still don't know if it's considered a bug that I was able to put such email in my app settings in the first place. Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Andrey, Thanks for sharing the link. Valuable information. We have contacted facebook and are waiting for them to send us an email. I tried what you did, by adding our email as an additional email to see if it is a valid email and it seems like it is. So now im just waiting. Thanks once again :)